# Graphql No Suitable resolver for my query

Tags: spring-boot, graphql

Try to did a simple graph query that suppose give me the `id` back but it give me following exception
`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not resolve parameter [0] in public com.vincent.graphqltutorial.entity.Game com.vincent.graphqltutorial.controller.GameController.findGameById(java.lang.Integer): No suitable resolver`

The query I try to call is

```
query ViewGame($gameId: Int!) {
  game(id: $gameId) {
    id
    __typename
  }
}
```

and I pass following graphql variables in

```
{
    "gameId":8779
}
```

In my graphql schema I have

```
type Game{
    id:Int!
 // other fields but not got queried
}
type Query{
    game(id:Int!):Game
}
```

And in my `Game` entity

```
@Data
@ToString
public class Game {
    Integer id;
    // other fields
}
```

On my `GameController.java`, I mapped it with `@QueryMapping` annotation

```
@Controller
@Slf4j
public class GameController{

    @Autowired
    GameService gameService;

    @QueryMapping(name="game")
    public Game findGameById(Integer id){
        log.info("Finding game with gameId {}", id);
        return gameService.findGameById(id);
    }

}
```

I also add the `@RestController` annotation to check do I get the initial setup, which it is return me the result with details of the `Game` object, however it failed on graphql query

Project Version:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.1'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.15.RELEASE'
}

group = 'com.vincent'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-graphql'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework:spring-webflux'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.graphql:spring-graphql-test'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found that.. one "silly" mistake I made.

In `findByGameId` method, inside the parameter I forgot to add `@Argument` annotation, once I add it in, it solved.